# How to perform load testing of java application

Tags: jmeter

As I'm new into performance testing, can anyone tell me what are the important factors to be considered for the performance using jmeter?

I able to generate the script using HTTP proxy server but NOT able to understand the best throughput value for the 100 users load. How should I analyze the throughput value & proceed further to check 5000 users load.

Please guide me on this ASAP.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Your question is too wide. There is a lot that goes on in a performance test depending on what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Agreed with @AnuragKapur performance varies based on your needs. However, throughput can be a good measure to know what you can handle with your setup.   JMeter has a page for the definitions of the performance measurements - [Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

Comment: Hi Anurag, Thanks for your reply. Here the target is to check how many users load can my application handle?

Comment: I wants to perform load as well as stress testing to find out the break point. I started with first 100 users. I recorded a script (which consists of 17 pages) and kept numbers of users 100, ramp-up period 10 & loop count 1 in thread group. When I run the test, I'm getting null value in tomcat. So am I done the setup in right way? On what basis I should analyze the result & proceed further?

Comment: "Getting null value in tomcat" - elaborate please; are you getting a null pointer exception (NPE)? If the application is throwing NPE, I would debug why that is as this is likely to be an application issue. To ensure your test setup is correct, I would start with 1 user and make sure all is well. Then take the number of users up (in steps of 10 or 100.. depends really)..

Comment: In general, once you have the tests setup correctly, I would increase the load in steps and monitor the throughput. After a certain point (as you increase the no. of. users) the throughput will stop increasing.. this is typically the max load or break point. You should also monitor the response time as you increase the load. You may find that after increasing the load beyond a point the response time rises to 2s (say) and this may be un-acceptable in your use case..

Comment: It might be a good idea to read about general approaches and guidelines for performance testing. A quick google search got me this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx

Overall, as I said in my first comment, there is a lot to consider. So a bit of reading may place you in a better place to carry on with your task. You can then ask specific questions that you may have.

Comment: I'm NOT getting any NPE, these values are coming from session. Currently I set 1 user only still getting the null value. 

Please help me out.

Comment: 18.02.2015 12:43:20 | info    | select userid from users where username='admin' and password='LTE4M-jEyMj-ExMTE-4MjEw-MTY5L'
1. UserValidate.jsp-->1<--->
2. index.jsp-->null<--->
3. Frames.jsp-->null<--->
4. Frames.jsp(branchid)--><--->
18.02.2015 12:43:20 | info    | select dd.dashboardid as dashboardid,dd.name as name from user_dashboard ud,dashboard_details dd where ud.dashboardid=dd.dashboardid and ud.branch_id='' and userid='null'

Comment: How do I set up 1 user in jmeter?

I followed the below steps:
1. Added a thread group and set 'numbers of users = 1', 'ramp-up period = 1' & 'loop count = 1' 
2. Recorded the script through HTTP proxy server.
3. Added the 'View Result Tree' & 'Graph Result' listners.
4. Run the test.

I'm getting the session id null, NOT getting any null pointer expection (NPE) in tomcat.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I'm NOT getting null value more. The problem has resolved by using the HTTP Cookie manager.

Then I took the numbers of users up in steps of 1, 10, 50 and 100 and checking throughput values. Kept the 'Ramp up period = 1' & 'Loop Count = 1'.
The values are increasing step by step.  But while running the 100 threads,  tomact gets hanged. 

Is this a correct way to check the user load? and why tomcat is hanged at the end?

Please help.